# In an html table, why doesn't header width change overall table width?

Tags: html

Check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/hQ9ZR/

```
<table background='red'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style='width:3000px;background:red'>Students</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shmoe</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

​

and the css is:

```
  html,body { overflow:auto; }
```

When I make the width of the Header 3000px I'd expect it to cause an overflow (scrollbar) in the page. But it doesn't. It's because the width of the header cell doesn't change the overall table's width.

If you set the width of the table to 3000px, you'll see the overflow (scrollbar)

So basically, I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so the table's width is defined by it's headers widths?

Thanks

Comment: Put a border on the table and you'll notice that it does.

Comment: Are you putting a max width on the containing element (div or body)?

Comment: Just a note. Adding inline styles is a crappy way to do things. It does get the example across of course. Those styles should be in a stylesheet and your table should get a class name as the hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not the way you style tables these days

```
<table background='red'>
```

use this instead

```
<table style="background:red;">
```

And secondly you need to use `min-width` for `th` instead of `width`

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hQ9ZR/3/)

```
<th style='border: 1px solid #fffff0;min-width:5000px;background:red'>Students</th>
```